# Part of tikz plot is missing

Tags: tikz-pgf

The last part of all my functions are missing. I have found a few similar posts here that suggested changing domain/samples. I tried a bunch of different values for samples up to 10000, but none of them solved the problem or caused memory errors. Any ideas how I can fix this?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,titlepage,12pt]{report}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\tikzset{>=latex}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs,quotes,arrows.meta}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h!]
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            unit vector ratio*=1 1 1,
            width=\textwidth,
            domain=0:18,
            xmin=0, xmax=18,
            ymin=0, ymax=18,
            xtick={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17},
            ytick={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17},
            samples=2000,
            axis y line=center,
            axis x line=middle,
            ]
            \draw (7,8.5) node[anchor=north west] {$h$};
            \addplot+[mark=none, color=black] {(17^3-x^3)^(1/3)};
            \addplot+[mark=none, color=black] {(16^3-x^3)^(1/3)};
            \addplot+[mark=none, color=black] {(15^3-x^3)^(1/3)};
            \addplot+[mark=none, color=black] {(14^3-x^3)^(1/3)};
            \addplot+[mark=none, color=black] {(13^3-x^3)^(1/3)};
            \addplot+[mark=none, color=black] {x};
            \addplot [only marks] table {
                8 13
                13 13
            };
            \addplot [only marks, color=red] table {
                7 7
                10 7
                2 3
            };
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\caption{My caption}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the corresponding lines of your code this way:

```
samples=1000,
            axis y line=center,
            axis x line=middle,
            ]
            \draw (7,8.5) node[anchor=north west] {$h$};
            \addplot+[mark=none, domain=0:17,color=black] {(17^3-x^3)^(1/3)};
            \addplot+[mark=none, domain=0:16, color=black] {(16^3-x^3)^(1/3)};
            \addplot+[mark=none, domain=0:15, color=black] {(15^3-x^3)^(1/3)};
            \addplot+[mark=none,  domain=0:14,color=black] {(14^3-x^3)^(1/3)};
            \addplot+[mark=none,  domain=0:13,color=black] {(13^3-x^3)^(1/3)};
```

The output now is:

[image]

Comment: Sweet and simple! Thanks!